# Exporting multiple shapes from Illustrator as one resizable object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, adobe-xd

I designed a map marker using Adobe Illustrator and I am trying to export this design so I can use it in Adobe XD.
When I export as a .png everything is ok.
But when I export as an SVG I have this problem when resizing it in Adobe XD:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried grouping the objects?  It seems to be resizing them individually.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug when importing SVG's which consist of grouped elements in illustrator (at least by drag and drop), because when the group is selected in Adobe XD, only one path will be resized while trying to resize. When the group is ungrouped in Adobe XD and recreated again, all paths are resizing proportionally.